# Dataframe: column, that checks for each row the value of the previos row and enters value

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dataframe

I've really tried a lot to solve the following problem, and I've read a lot about it. But still, I can't manage it

See this example:

```
time <- sample(1:300, 20)
test <- c (0,0,0, NA, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, NA, 0,0, 3, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 3, 0)
take <- rep(NA, 20)
df <-data.frame(time, test, take)
> head(df, 8)
  time test take
1  271    0   NA
2  147    0   NA
3  277    0   NA
4  247   NA   NA
5   82    0   NA
6  133    0   NA
7  231    3   NA
8  110    0   NA
```

Now I want to enter values in the last (take) column. The value there is dependent on conditions in the second column (test). If it's a NA or a 3, it can remain empty. Okay so far,
but my problem is the value 0. It should put an "a" into the row,  if the value of the previous row is 0, but a "b" if it is 3, and "c" for the rest.

therefore the output should look like this:

```
head(df, 8)
      time test take
    1  271    0   c
    2  147    0   a
    3  277    0   a
    4  247   NA   NA
    5   82    0   c
    6  133    0   a
    7  231    3   NA
    8  110    0   b
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
is0<-which(df$test==0) # indices of test elements = 0
df[is0,"take"]<-"c" # for each test=0, put take="c", as it is the "default" value
for (i in setdiff(is0,1)){ # for each test=0 that is not the first one (because the first row doesn't have a previous row)
    if((i-1) %in% is0) df$take[i]<-"a" else if(df$test[i-1]==3 & !is.na(df$test[i-1])) df$take[i]<-"b" # if in the previous row test=0 then take="a", if it is 3 (and not NA), take="b"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
indx <- c(FALSE,!df$test[-nrow(df)] & !is.na(df$test)[-nrow(df)])
indx1 <- c(FALSE,df$test[-nrow(df)]==3 & !is.na(df$test)[-nrow(df)])
indx2 <- df$test==3|is.na(df$test)

df$take <- c('c','a','b', NA)[as.numeric(factor(1+2*indx+4*indx1+8*indx2))]

 df$take
 #[1] "c" "a" "a" NA  "c" "a" NA  "b" "a" NA  "c" "a" NA  "b" "a" NA  "c" "a" NA 
 #[20] "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using package `dplyr`, you can split your problem into two parts.

Part 1: write a function that encapsulates your logic to fill in `take` based on the previous rows.

```
return_value_based_on_previous_row <- function(x, lagged) {

    if (is.na(x) | x == 3) {
        temp = NA
    } else {

        if (is.na(lagged)) {
            temp = "c"
        } else if (lagged == 0) {
         temp = "a"
        } else if (lagged == 3) {
         temp = "b"
        } 

    }

    return(as.character(temp))

}
```

Part 2: use `lag` and `mutate` to work on `df` row by row.

```
df <-
    df %>% 
    mutate(lag_test = lag(test)) %>% # make temp column which contains previous value of test
    rowwise() %>% # makes the following mutate work on each row separately
    mutate(take = return_value_based_on_previous_row(test, lag_test)) %>%
    select(-lag_test) #remove temp column
```

which gives:

```
> df
   time test take
1   164    0    c
2    36    0    a
3   279    0    a
4   255   NA   NA
5   241    0    c
6   188    0    a
7   117    3   NA
8    75    0    b
9    60    0    a
10  175   NA   NA
11  238    0    c
12  184    0    a
13  272    3   NA
14  215    0    b
15   49    0    a
16  204   NA   NA
17  291    0    c
18  218    0    a
19  197    3   NA
20  138    0    b
```